# Spring Custom Value Resolver

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple spring boot application and I would like to write a custom value resolver for something like this:

```
@Value("${APPL:key}"
private value;
```

Now I need to extract the placeholder, parse it and resolve it by a custom resolver. If the pattern of the placeholder doesn't match a certain pattern, the standard resolving mechanism of spring should be in place.

I would appreciate any ideas to solve my problems.
Thanx in advance.